# get all distinct values for a specific column across multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query that returns all tables that contain the column `PROGRAM_ID`. Is there a way that I can return all distinct values across all tables in a database that contain the column `PROGRAM_ID`?

```
select table_name from all_tab_columns where column_name = 'PROGRAM_ID';
```

Comment: I dont think this is possible without using `union all` for all tables returned by your query.

Comment: you can do it through dynamic SQL

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a SQL query that you can then copy and paste manually:

```
select case when rownum > 1 then 'union ' end
  || 'select program_id from ' || owner || '.' || table_name
from all_tab_columns where column_name = 'PROGRAM_ID';
```

which produces output like:

```
select program_id from SYS.V_$SQLAREA_PLAN_HASH
union select program_id from SYS.V_$SQLAREA
union select program_id from SYS.V_$SQL
union select program_id from SYS.GV_$SQLAREA
union select program_id from SYS.GV_$SQLAREA_PLAN_HASH
union select program_id from SYS.GV_$SQL
union select program_id from MY_SCHEMA.TABLE_A
union select program_id from MY_SCHEMA.TABLE_B
union select program_id from MY_SCHEMA.TABLE_C
```

so you may want to filter the users being retrieved; or switch to `user_tab_columns` (and lose the `owner` part) if you're only interested in tables in your own schema.

If you want to identify and query the tables in one go you can do the same thing but as dynamic SQL. This will open a ref cursor that has the results, in this demo using the SQL*Plus and SQL Developer `variable` and `print` commands:

```
var rc refcursor;

declare
  l_stmt clob;
begin
  select listagg(case when rownum > 1 then 'union ' end
    || 'select program_id from ' || owner || '.' || table_name, ' ')
    within group (order by null)
  into l_stmt
  from all_tab_columns where column_name = 'PROGRAM_ID';

  open :rc for l_stmt;
end;
/

print rc
```